# Problem with displaying data from table with .closest("tr")

Tags: javascript, arrays

iam using 2 modals (Bootstrap) with different contents I now want to display data from a table in Input fields in my Modal. There is an edit button in the row, thats why iam using closest.

With 1 Modal it yesterday worked with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".trigger_popup").on("click", function(){
    $(".modal").modal("show");
    $(".trigger_close").on("click", function(){
    $(".modal").modal("hide"); 
    })
    $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
    var data = $tr.children("td").map(function(){ 
      return $(this).text().trim("");
      
    }).get();
    console.log(data);
    $("#name").val(data[1])
    $("#model").val(data[2])
    $("#facturer").val(data[3])
    $("#serial").val(data[4])
    $("#place").val(data[6])
    $("#notes").val(data[7])
    $("#updated").val(data[8])
    $("#added").val(data[9])
  })
})
```

now the code is this:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
            $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
        var data = $tr.children("td").map(function(){ 
          return $(this).text().trim("");
          
        }).get();
        console.log(data);
        $("#name").val(data[1])
        $("#model").val(data[2])
        $("#facturer").val(data[3])
        $("#serial").val(data[4])
        $("#place").val(data[6])
        $("#notes").val(data[7])
        $("#updated").val(data[8])
        $("#added").val(data[9])
      })
        })
```

this is my HTML Code:

```
<div class="table11">
    
          <table id="myTable">
                                  <tr>
                                  <th style="display:none;"></th>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Modell</th>
                                    <th>Hersteller</th>
                                    <th>Seriennummer</th>
                                    <th>Bestand</th>
                                    <th style="display:none;"></th>
                                    <th style="display:none;"></th>
                                    <th style="display:none;"></th>
                                    <th style="display:none;"></th>
                          
                                    <th></th>
                                  </tr>
            <tr>
            <td style='display: none;'>id</td>
            <td>name</td>
            <td>model</td>
            <td>facturer</td>
            <td>serial</td>
            <td>count</td>
            <td style='display: none;'>place</td>
            <td style='display: none;'>notes</td>
            <td style='display: none;'>updated</td>
            <td style='display: none;'>added</td>
            <td><i data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg" class="icon fa-solid fa-eye"></i></td>';
            <td><a><i class="icon fa-solid fa-circle-minus"></i></a></td>';
          </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        

          <!------------------------------------------------>

<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form action="inserts.php" method="POST" id="form">
              <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control mb-1" name="name" placeholder="Produkttyp" value="" autocomplete="off">
              <input type="text" id="model" class="form-control mb-1" name="model" placeholder="Modell"  autocomplete="off">
              <input type="text" id="facturer" class="form-control mb-1" name="facturer" placeholder="Hersteller"  autocomplete="off">
              <input type="text" id="serial" class="form-control mb-1" name="serial" placeholder="Seriennummer"  autocomplete="off">
              <input type="text" id="place" class="form-control mb-1" name="place" placeholder="Ablageort" autocomplete="off">
              <input type="text" id="notes" class="form-control mb-1" name="notes" placeholder="Notiz"   autocomplete="off">
              <input type="text" id="updated" class="form-control mb-1" name="updated" placeholder="zuletzt geändert"  readonly autocomplete="off">
              <input type="text" id="added" class="form-control mb-1" name="added" placeholder="hinzugefügt" readonly  autocomplete="off">
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" name="save" class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color: #F9B711; color: black;border: none;">Änderungen speichern</button>
            </form>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary trigger_close"  data-dismiss="modal" style="background-color: red; color: black; border: none;">schließen</button>
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Small modal -->

<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form action="inserts.php" method="POST" id="form">
              <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control mb-1" name="name" placeholder="Produkttyp" autocomplete="off">
                      <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control mb-1" name="model" placeholder="Modell"  autocomplete="off">
                      <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control mb-1" name="facturer" placeholder="Hersteller"  autocomplete="off">
                      <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control mb-1" name="serial" placeholder="Seriennummer"  autocomplete="off">
                      <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control mb-1" name="count" placeholder="Anzahl"  autocomplete="off">
                      <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control mb-1" name="place" placeholder="Ablageort" autocomplete="off">
                      <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control mb-1" name="notes" placeholder="Notiz"   autocomplete="off">
                      <select name="w" class="form-select">
                          <option value="NULL">Warnung bei niedrigem Bestand?</option>
                          <option value="y">Ja</option>
                          <option value="n">Nein</option>
                        </select>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" name="send" class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color: #F9B711; color: black;border: none;">einlagern</button>
            </form>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary create_close" data-dismiss="modalcreate" style="background-color: red; color: black; border: none;">schließen</button>
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want that the data from the table (closest) is displayed in the Inputs from the first modal.

Comment: Your question is unclear (to me, at least). Do you want to fill in the inputs in the modal with the values from the table, on button click, like in [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/zwpdb92r/)? Btw, you have bad HTML syntax in your modal - multiple elements have the same id (name), and some tags are not closed within their parents. [Validate your HTML](https://validator.w3.org/) before using your code in production.

Comment: Yes, i want to fill the Inputs, with 1 modal it worked and after changing the code it stopped working

Comment: Again, you need to validate your HTML syntax. You have elements which are not closed within their parents - for example, `<div><form></div></form>`. This is wrong, and should be corrected. Also, `id` and `name` attributes must be unique - they seem to be repeating between the two modals. Please use a validation service of some sort to eliminate these errors first. Also - in your second jQuery codeblock, you're using `$('#exampleModal')`. There's no such element in the HTML you posted. Neither of your two modals has an id attribute.